# 502 bad gateway with nginx in network calls

Tags: nginx, tomcat, load-balancing, geoserver, round-robin

I set up load balancing on NGINX using the Round Robin for apache tomcat servers with two servers in my `proxy.conf` file:

```
upstream appcluster1 {
    server IP_ADDRESS1:8000;
    server IP_ADDRESS2:8001;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://appcluster1;
    }

}
```

For more details, I am running Geoserver with each of the tomcat server. For the first `IP_ADDRESS1`, I am successfully able to make calls to it and get layers returned (say if geoserver on the `IP_ADDRESS2` is down). However, if I switch it and try to make calls to `IP_ADDRESS2` (and `IP_ADDRESS1` is down), I am unable to get all of the tiles back from Geoserver. In the network calls, I get a mixture of 200 and 502 errors.

The two geoserver is exactly the same and not any different from one another. Does anyone know why this is the case -- one Geoserver is able to return calls successfull but the other one only gets partial results back. I am doing all of this using NGINX and the round robin method..

I also tried to set `proxy_next_upstream` to `off` but that didn't seem to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a Tomcat instance running at `IP_ADDRESS2:8001`? Try connecting to this Tomcat directly. If both Tomcat's are configured in the same way, isn't the second one also listening on port `8000`?

Comment: what do the GeoServer logs say is the problem?

Comment: @IanTurton I don't see anything particular in the Geoserver logs.. perhaps it has to do with the way nginx is doing the round robin method

Comment: If the requests don't get to GeoServer then it's an nginx issue